# LINQ: Sort by (Treat letters as numbers)

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects

How should i use linq to sort my data when my data contain both numbers and letters?

For example my current linq

```
Dim MyQuery = From c In XDoc.Descendants() _
Where c.Attribute(Y) IsNot Nothing And c.Attribute(Str) IsNot Nothing _
Order By Val(c.Attribute(Y).Value), Val(c.Attribute(X).Value) _
Select Str = c.Attribute(Str)
```

returns something like the following

```
13
167   
172   
231      
44    
49
```

which is not what i would like it to be...
The output should be like the one below

```
13
44    
49 
167   
172   
231
```

Any ideas?
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `Value` property of `XAttribute` - use the [explicit conversion to `Integer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358993.aspx). I *think* this should do it:

```
Dim MyQuery = From c In XDoc.Descendants() _
Where c.Attribute(Y) IsNot Nothing And c.Attribute(Str) IsNot Nothing _
Order By CInt(c.Attribute(Y)), CInt(c.Attribute(X)) _
Select Str = c.Attribute(Str)
```

Note that it's generally a better idea to use the explicit conversions supported by `XAttribute` and `XElement` than to use `Int32.Parse` etc, as then the XML-specific parsing will be performed, following the appropriate standard formats.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the strings to numbers in your sort clause, e.g.

```
Dim MyQuery = From c In XDoc.Descendants() _
Where c.Attribute(Y) IsNot Nothing And c.Attribute(Str) IsNot Nothing _
Order By CInt(c.Attribute(Y)), CInt(c.Attribute(X)) _
Select Str = c.Attribute(Str)
```

Note that if any of the strings cannot be converted to an `int` (or whatever numeric type you decide you need to use) then you will get an exception. In this case, you will have to do something a little more involved, such as projecting your sequence onto a new sequence with any strings representing numerics converted to numerics and the rest left as they are, the result being alphanumeric sorting.

Comment: Why use `int.Parse` when LINQ to XML already supports conversion to integer directly?

Comment: @Jon - I did in fact have `int` casting in there to start with but I had it against `.Value` which I realised wouldn't work, so I changed it to `int.Parse()`. I didn't think about the explicit conversion to integer, thanks for the reminder - have edited.

Comment: good point - have edited. now my code matches yours ;-) I'll leave my answer in for the sake of the added info I've included regarding possible exceptions (otherwise I'd delete it and let your answer supersede)